# How to retain form data in a multi form page

Tags: jsf

I am working on JSF. I have an xhtml page with multiple forms. when i am submitting one form, and if i had made some changes on other form i am loosing it, as on submit the page is getting refreshed. I cannot use a single form. is there any way to do.

any solution will be highly appreciated.

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using JSF 2.x (your statement that you're using XHTML (Facelets) confirms this less or more), just submit the form by ajax.

It's a matter of adding the following tag to the command links/buttons of the form:

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
```

This way the current `<h:form>` will be submitted by ajax and the current `<h:form>` only will be rendered (updated/refreshed). You can if necessary specify other to-be-updated components in the `render` attribute by adding other client ID(s).

If you're still on the old JSF 1.x, you may want to look at Ajax4jsf sublibrary of RichFaces which supports basically the same.